# How to define an environmental variable to hold current time in Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

What I'm trying is to define an `ENV` variable that will hold current time inside a docker container. Using bash, I can simply state `timenow=$(date+"%y%m%d")` and voila, if I `echo $timenow` I see the captured time in the specified format print to the console.

Here goes my Dockerfile:
What is written below does not work, any tips on how to do it will be very much appreciated sirs.

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Me
ENV timenow ""
RUN /bin/bash -c "timenow=$(date +'%y-%m-%d')"
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo $timenow"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with

```
FROM ubuntu
LABEL maintainer="Me"
ARG TIMENOW
ENV TIMENOW $TIMENOW
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo $TIMENOW"]
```

and then

```
docker build --build-arg TIMENOW=$(date +'%y-%m-%d') --tag my_image:latest .
docker run -it --rm my_image:latest
```

which should display the time the image was built, which is what I belive you want.

Edit:

If you want the current time at the moment the contaier was executed, then the following should work

```
FROM ubuntu
LABEL maintainer="Me"
CMD TIMENOW=$(date+"%y%m%d") && echo $TIMENOW
```

and then

```
docker build --tag my_image:latest .
docker run -it --rm my_image:latest
```

Comment: I want to display the time the container started to run actually. Know any exit to this my good sir?